# How can I obtain the first and last days of months that fall between two dates? And use a third date to condition where the dates are registered?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, conditional-statements, timedelta

I have a dataframe where I have three columns: x_date, y_date and next_month_day. The first two are always different for every row, and the last is always constant. The idea is to iterate over the dataframe and obtain the individual months between x_date and next_month_day. y_date sets a condition in there aswell.
Let's see this example:

For the first row of my dataframe I have the three values in here:

- x_date = '2023-02-13'
- y_date = '2023-04-15'
- next_month_day = '2023-07-01'

and the resulting dataframe must be like this one (Table A):[image: Examples Tables]

I will try to explain it here, although the image has the main idea:
The resulting dataframe has four columns, and the months "before" the y_date are registered in the first two "adhoc" columns. Once we reach the month that contains the y_date, we set the first two columns as the first day of the month, and the day BEFORE the y_date, respectively, while the other two columns have the y_date and the last day of the month. After this, the remaining months are registered in the "real" columns only.

Another two examples are also in tables B and C. There might be cases where both x_date and y_date are equal (eg: both '2023-02-13', like in table B), and also both dates might be in the first month we retrieve (like in table C).

So, the y_date conditions in which columns we register the dates.

Would really appreciate your help. Thank you

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Since I have a dataframe, I tried using this for-loop, but it doesnt work well (sometimes registers the dates in the wrong columns, and also fails to recognize the case where we should be using all 4 columns).

`for parameter, row in df_with_dates.iterrows():

```
    # Convert dates to pandas datetime objects
    x_date = pd.to_datetime(row['x_date'])
    y_date = pd.to_datetime(row['y_date'])
    next_month_day = pd.to_datetime(row['next_month_day'])

    num_months = (next_month_day.year - x_date.year) * 12 + (next_month_day.month - x_date.month)

    # Create an empty DataFrame to store the results
    df_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['first_date_adhoc', 'last_date_adhoc', 'first_date_real', 'last_date_real'])

    # Iterate over the range of months
    for i in range(num_months):
        # Calculate the first_date and last_date for each month
        if i == 0:
            first_date = x_date
        else:
            first_date = x_date + relativedelta(months=i)
            first_date = first_date.replace(day=1)

        last_date = first_date + relativedelta(day=31)
        last_date = min(last_date, next_month_day)  

        # Determine the column names based on the y_date condition:
        if y_date >= first_date and y_date <= last_date:
            df_result = df_result.append(
                {'first_date_adhoc': first_date, 'last_date_adhoc': last_date, 'first_date_real': None,
                 'last_date_real': None}, ignore_index=True)
        else:
            df_result = df_result.append(
                {'first_date_adhoc': None, 'last_date_adhoc': None, 'first_date_real': first_date,
                 'last_date_real': last_date}, ignore_index=True)`
```

And used df_result to store the results in the For loop.